# Kubernetes - env variables as API url

Tags: api, kubernetes

So I have an API that's the gateway for two other API's.
Using docker in wsl 2 (ubuntu), when I build my Gateway API.

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -e A_API_URL=$A_API_URL B_API_URL=$B_API_URL  registry:$(somePort)//gateway
```

I have 2 environnement variables that are the API URI of the two API'S. I just dont know how to make this work in the config.

```
 env:
    - name: A_API_URL
      value: <need help>
    - name: B_API_URL
      value: <need help>
```

I get 500 or 502 errors when accessing then in the network.
I tried specifyng the value of the env var as:

- their respective service's name.
- the complete URI (http://$(addr):$(port)
- the relative path : /something/anotherSomething

Each API is deployed with a Deployment controller and a service
I'm at a lost, any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to hardwire them. Kubernetes doesn't know anything about your local machine. There are templating tools like Helm that could inject things like Bash is in your `docker run` example but generally not a good idea since if anyone other than you runs the same command, they could see different results. The values should look like `http://servicename.namespacename.svc.cluster.local:port/whatever`. So if the service is named `foo` in namespace `default` with port 8000 and path /api, `http://foo.default.svc.cluster.local:8000/api`.

Comment: I tried your idea and its not working. 
I got it working by hardcoding the ip address of the svc, but this obviously can't stay like this.
I assume your way is what I need to make work for kubernets to manage the ip by itself, i'll continue in this path

Comment: Nvm my previous comment, my path's are managed another way so this works if I dont write anything after :port. Thanks a lot!